# python nosetests won't work

Tags: python, nose

I was learning Python from 'learning python the hard way' and I was stuck at exercise 46 (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html).

I installed pip and then the nose package and whenever i run nosetest now as in the example it doesn't work. This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/nosetests", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2807, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 594, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: nose==1.3.0
```

I googled about this but couldn't find an answer.
I am on a Lubuntu 13.04 desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a version of `nose` equal to `1.3.0` (maybe the `nose` version that you installed is not `1.3.0`?)

You can find out what version of `nose` you have installed with

```
>>> import nose
>>> nose.__version__
'1.3.0'
```

Using `pip` this is as simple as (if you already have `nose` installed then you will want to use the `--upgrade` flag)

```
pip install --upgrade nose==1.3.0
```

or even direct from the website

```
pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nose/nose-1.3.0.tar.gz#md5=95d6d32b9d6b029c3c65674bd9e7eabe
```

Comment: if I do nose.__version__ 
I get: '1.1.2'

but when I try to install the last version with pip install nose==1.3.0, it tells me:
`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose==1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade nose==1.3.0`

Comment: already tried that, no luck.
that gives me this:
`Requirement already up-to-date: nose==1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`